# How To Programmatically Apply Borders To A Range

Tags: c#, excel

Good morning!  I have researched my question, and have found certain variations to an answer, but not the exact answer I need.

Below is a 4-line snippet of a very large Excel worksheet formatting block.  I'm trying to take these four lines of code down to a single line, using a Range. All of my attempts have come up just short of being the proper syntax.  I would greatly appreciate any help.

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2].Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight = 1d;
xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 3].Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight = 1d;
xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 4].Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight = 1d;
xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 5].Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight = 1d;
```

Thanks!

Keith

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single for-loop

Try this one:

```
for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++)
{
   xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, i].Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight = 1d;
}
```

Comment: Oh, just readen the description again, you tell me that it needs to happen with Range? There is a specific reason for that? Anyways, I cannot help you further for that.

Comment: Hi Steven.  No, I doesn't NEED to be used with a range statement.  I only meant that I have a range of cells that I'd like to format using as few lines of code as possible.  I'm trying your example now.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Ah, thanks, Same as me, I'll try to keep repeating code at a minimal, and that's also a thing every programmer must do everytime. Learning to connect loops and arrays can really help you out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For a Range

```
xlWorkSheet.get_Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2], excelSheet.Cells[3, 5]).Borders ...
```

(However that would only set the boder of the rightmost member cell, if you wanted to set them all pass `xlInsideVertical`.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Alex.  I added the following statement...


`xlWorkSheet.get_Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2], xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 5]).Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical].Weight = 1d;`


When running this code, I got the following error...


'object' does not contain a definition for 'get_Range'


Any thoughts on this error?